The V.I. Arnold Primary School Problem 5
I've been working on the 5th problem from V.I. Arnold's Problems for Children from 5 to 15, and I could use some help. Here's the problem (I've rephrased it for clarity):
Alice and Bob traveled between cities A and B: Alice traveled from A to B, and Bob traveled from B to A. They both traveled at constant speeds and left at sunrise. They met at noon and continued to their respective destinations. Bob arrived at A at 4 pm, and Alice arrived at B at 9 pm. What time was sunrise?
Here's my approach:

Let the total distance between the cities be d.
Let the distance from city A to their meeting point be c.
Let the time from sunrise to noon be x.

A picture might help illustrate this:

I used these equations to set up the problem:
For Alice:

Speed of Alice is $\frac{\text{Distance to the meeting point}}{\text{Time from sunrise to noon}} = \frac{c}{x}$
Speed of Alice is also $\frac{\text{Total distance}}{\text{Total time}} = \frac{d}{x+9}$

So, $\frac{c}{x} = \frac{d}{x+9}$, which simplifies to:
$$ dx = c(x + 9) \tag{i} $$
For Bob:

Speed of Bob is $\frac{\text{Distance to the meeting point}}{\text{Time from sunrise to noon}} = \frac{d-c}{x}$
Speed of Bob is also $\frac{\text{Total distance}}{\text{Total time}} = \frac{d}{x+4}$

So, $\frac{d-c}{x} = \frac{d}{x+4}$, which simplifies to:
$$ dx = (d-c)(x + 4) \tag{ii} $$
Now, comparing equations (i) and (ii):
$$ c(x + 9) = (x + 4)(d - c) $$
$$ x = \frac{4d - 13c}{2c - d} $$
I'm stuck at this point and feel like I've used all the information provided in the problem. How should I proceed from here?
I've seen the solution online (The answer is supposed to be 6 am) but I want to understand what’s wrong with my approach or how I can progress using the same method.
Thanks for any help!


Find another expression for $x$. For instance, Eq. (i) yields
$$
x=\frac{9c}{d-c}. \tag{iii}
$$
Substituting this result in your last equation gives
$$
\frac{9c}{d-c}=\frac{4d-13c}{2c-d}. \tag{iv}
$$
Solve Eq. (iv) to find $c$ as a function of $d$ (or $d$ as a function of $c$).
Substitute the result in (iii) to find $x$.
Subtract $x$ from $12$.

